# Does it possible make IntelliJ display hint more robust?

Tags: java, coding-style, editor, intellij-idea, hint

I used long time Eclipse. In Eclipse it possible to press F2 and hints (e.g. about error) don't disappears and I can also copy the message directly from hint.
But in IntelliJ Idea (start to using now) hints are displayed for few milliseconds. 
Does it possible fix by settings or changes in config file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `Help > Default Keymap Reference` in the IntelliJ menu.  Perhaps `Ctrl-q` or `Ctrl-F1` are what you're looking for?

You can always remap keys in IDEA and not all functions have a keystroke by default, but they can be added.